# How to set command output as env. variable in windows cmd?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, azure, terraform

I have saved azure storage key in key vault and i want to retrieve the key using Azure cli and set it as env. variable in window cmd before i run terraform script.

Below listed command doesn't work, can anyone tell me what needs to be changed ?

set ARM_ACCESS_KEY=$(az keyvault secret show --name terraform-backend-key --vault-name myKeyVault -query value -o tsv)

Answer (score 1):

`Export` is what you need to set environment variable

Example below should work;

`export ARM_ACCESS_KEY=$(az keyvault secret show --name terraform-backend-key --vault-name myKeyVault -query value -o tsv)`